# Не получается проверить, пустой ли массив

Tags: javascript, jquery

Привет. Использую библиотеку [Arg.js](https://github.com/stretchr/arg.js) для парсинга параметров URL. Когда хочу запарсить все параметры, то использую метод `Arg.all()`. Но мне нужно отлавливать ситуацию, когда в адресной строке нет параметров. И проблема в том, что при отсутствии каких-либо параметров `Arg.all()` возвращает это:

```
Object {"": undefined}
```

Если сделать `typeof JSON.stringify(Arg.all())`, то в вывод попадёт `"string"`, а не `Array` или `Object`. Этот объект не берёт ни один известный мне метод:

```
$.isEmptyObject(Arg.all())
typeof Arg.all() !== 'undefined'
Arg.all().length !== 0
```

Я так понимаю, что использую **Arg.js** у меня не выйдет проверить наличие параметров в URL. Как мне проверить, нету ли каких-либо параметров в URL без **Arg.js**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самый простой способ проверить, есть ли какие-то get параметры - посмотреть на длину [строки с ними](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_search.asp)

```
!!location.search.length
```

Вот такая штука распарсит параметры на массив с объектами ключ-значение (только в первом осталось знак вопроса убрать)

```
// Строка с get параметрами
location.search
  //Убираем ведущий знак вопроса (если есть)
  .replace('?','')
  // разбиваем на отдельные параметры
  .split('&')

  // Это нужно, чтобы '' не превратилось в [''] 
  // и не возникла проблема, озвученная в вопросе
  .filter(el => el) 

  // Каждый параметер теперь разбиваем на ключ и значение
  .map(el => {
    let t = el.split('='); 
    return {[t[0]]:t[1]}
  });
```

Или еще круче, есть такая вешь как [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) -

```
let searchParams = new URLSearchParams(paramsString);
```

[Только поддержка хромает](https://caniuse.com/#search=URLSearchParams)

Comment: И что это даёт? Что без параметров, что с параметром `?parameter=test` возвращает `1`

Comment: @JamesJGoodwin С параметром будет 2. Вы, вероятно, его просто ручками приписали, поэтому js его не видит

Comment: @JamesJGoodwin Хотя да, 2 будет с 2 параметрами

Comment: написал в адресной строке `example.com?parameter=test` и загрузил с ним страницу. Открыл консоль, вбил строчку.

Comment: @JamesJGoodwin На верном пути) осталось включить мозг и чуть поднажать, и всё получится

Comment: Окей, я поменял `&` на `?`. Выходит, если в адресной строке нет параметров, то length всегда будет `1`, а если параметров 1 или больше, то length будет `2`?

Comment: @JamesJGoodwin А я тем временем нашел, как они получают такой объект) `location.search.split('&').map(el => {let t = el.split('='); return {[t[0]]:t[1]}});`

Comment: @JamesJGoodwin по идее можно банально так проверять - `!!location.search.length`, потому что если параметров вообще нету, то эта строка должна быть пуста

Comment: Вот `!!location.search.length`, пожалуй, удовлетворит мою любовь к булевым значениям.

Comment: Добавьте комментарий с `!!location.search.length` в ответ, пожалуйста.

Comment: Перед сплит неплохо было бы удалить `?`

Comment: @JamesJGoodwin добавил.

Answer (score 2):

Метод `.all` пытается разобрать как параметры из `querystring`, так и из `hash`

Для этого в метод `parse`, он передает [строку](https://github.com/stretchr/arg.js/blob/master/src/arg.js#L232)

```
var merged = Arg.parse(Arg.querystring() + "&" + Arg.hashstring());
```

Что в конечном итоге и дает объект с одним свойством.

Для проверки можно использовать метод [hasOwnProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty)

```
if(Arg.all().hasOwnProperty('') && Arg.all()['']===undefined){
    // нет параметров
}
```

---

Однако, если пользоваться методом [.query](https://github.com/stretchr/arg.js/blob/master/src/arg.js#L247), то данной ситуации можно будет избежать, так как будет возвращен пустой объект.